# Disadvantages of using OpenGL in Android app?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is there any tradeoff of add some OpenGL to a "serious" (not game) Android app?

The reason why I want to use OpenGL, is to add some 3d behaviour to a few views.

According to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html OpenGL 1.0 is available in every Android device and doesn't require modification of manifest file. So there will never be compatibility issues.

The only 2 things I can think about is 1. mantainability by other developers which can't OpenGL. And possible 2. Integration problems with other components / not well reusable (although, not sure).

Is there also anything else, unexpected things, overhead of some sort, complications, etc.?

Asking because it seems not to be a very popular practice, people seem to prefer to "fake" the 3d with 2d or give it up. Don't know if it's only because they don't want to learn OpenGL.

Comment: If you plan to support the standard app workflow, it becomes difficult to manage multiple screens using opengl to do this. In the newest devices, hardware acceleration is supported which would push work to the gpu when it can. The startup/teardown needed to run opengl makes switching context/activities very painful to the end user.

Comment: Which startup/teardown do you mean?

Comment: Well, in your case adding some 3d specific functionality to a custom view may not add significant overhead but in a decent sized game, setting up the glcontext and getting assets loaded in memory takes some time. This context is lost on pause and needs recreated on resume which causes some lag. It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you mean that the bitmaps are loaded to a different memory than usual memory and this takes more time? Otherwise this would apply to all kind of games / graphic intensive apps. And what about setting up the glcontext takes much time?

Comment: Like you say this will probably not be appliable for me since not very grafic or animation intensive. But I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenGL for some visualization in a released app, and I have an uncaught exception handler in place to catch any exception coming from the GLThread and disable OpenGL the next time the app is run, since I had some crash reports in the internals of GLSurfaceView.java coming in from buggier devices. If the 3D rendering is not crucial to your app, this is one approach you can take so that users with these devices can continue to use the app.

From Android 3.0+ you can also preserve the EGL context by calling GLSurfaceView. setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);. You'll only really need to do this if your renderer is very expensive to initialize, and it only works if you're not destroying the GLSurfaceView in between (i.e. the default behavior of an activity when rotating the device). If you're not loading that many resources then initializing OpenGL is usually fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) docs (emphasis mine):

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; **the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window** to allow its surface to be displayed. The view hierarchy will take care of correctly compositing with the Surface any siblings of the SurfaceView that would normally appear on top of it. This can be used to place overlays such as buttons on top of the Surface, though note however that it can have an impact on performance since a full alpha-blended composite will be performed each time the Surface changes.

The advantage is that your GL thread can update the screen independently of the UI thread (i.e. it doesn't need to render to a texture and render the texture to the screen); the disadvantage is that *something* needs to composite your view with the screen. If you're lucky, this can be done in the "hardware composer"; otherwise it is done on the GPU and may be a bit wasteful of GPU resources (see *For Butter or Worse: Smoothing Out Performance in Android UIs* at [27:32](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE#t=1652s) and [40:23](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Q8m9sHdyXnE#t=2423s)).

If your view is small, it may be better to use a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). This will render to a texture and render the texture as part of the normal view hierarchy which might be better, but can increase latency. The downside is it's only available since API level 14.